# Quad Band GSM PCB Antenna

Tags: antenna, gsm

I am making a GSM + GPS Board, and we don't want to put an external antenna on top of it via any sort of connection.

Primariliy to reduce the cost. I've seen a VTS system with an onboard antenna which gives good enough signal even when the unit is in the basement or indoors.

Now i am not getting any sample reference or guides to work on it. Anyone can point me a guide / pdf / page where these things are xplained ?

We dont want to purchase an antenna we want to have an antenna on our PCB board itself.

Here's a Picture of the Antenna[image]

Comment: VTS system? Operating frequencies? What things need explaining?

Comment: VTS : Vehicle Tracking System
Operating Freq : 850/900/1800/1900 MHz
I need like a guide or a reference to how to make a PCB antenna for that frequency.

Comment: Maybe you have a photograph of the one you have seen?

Comment: Attached Picture

Comment: Too close GSM antenna to GPS antenna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you realize that antenna design is a very large and complex subject ! It might look like just a strip of conductive material (and actually it is :) ) but there's more to it than that. If you want the best performance (and you do since you want the product to operate in a basement) then you will need a "proper" antenna. If your antenna is not "proper" you might suffer from:

- less transmission power because of impedance mismatch
- less receiver sensitivity because of impedance mismatch
- the antenna's radiation pattern might not be what you want

I don't think that just making a certain shape using the copper on a standard PCB will result in a very good antenna. For sure it will work but it will not be optimal. I would advise you to look into ready-made antennas that can be mounted on a PCB, [here's an example](http://cpc.farnell.com/1/1/192091-siretta-echo12-x-x-s-s-3-antenna-gsm-gprs-3g-penta-band-pifa.html). Note how it has a complexly shaped conductive area ! Also look at the datasheet, all information is there and it is guaranteed by the manufacturer. You cannot get that when you just make "some antenna" on your PCB by yourself (unless you are an antenna expert of course).